How to show dialog in accessibility service?
i wanted to show a dialog from my accessibility service, but from normal way (creating dialog and attaching content view and invoke show method ... ) i receive this error:
Unable to add window -- token null is not valid; is your activity running?
The code:
AlertDialog.Builder(applicationContext, R.style.DialogTheme)
            .apply {
                setTitle("Test")
                setMessage("Test2")
                create()
                show()
            }

also i tried to set ACCESSIBILITY OVERLAY type to the alert window but it didn't make any diffrence.
How can i show a alert or bottom sheet from my accessibility service?
i tried to set ACCESSIBILITY OVERLAY type to the alert window but it didn't make any diffrence.

why do you want to a different dialog for accessibility, you can use the same dialog for accessibility from the current screen
